# CentOs 6.3 x64 installed with no GUI

Tags: linux, centos, graphical-user-interface

I downloaded a fresh ISO of CentOs 6.3 from [here](http://centos.fis.uniroma2.it/6.3/isos/x86_64/). After installing successfully, CentOs loads a text based linux.

How do i load the GUI?

Answer (score 3):

You can run:

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

And possibly change the `/etc/inittab` to default to runlevel 5.

Comment: Thanks. Running the "yum" results in an error: "...could not retrieve mirrorlist..."

Answer (score 1):

After the installation is complete, edit the /etc/inittab and change the 'initdefault' line so that it is set to the value of 5 (instead of 3).  Then reboot.

Comment: I changed 3 to 5. The system loaded up to the bluish-gray bar and seems stuck.

Comment: If you hit Escape while the bar is showing, it will dump you to a console and show you service startup progress.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Thanks. I got to "starting crond  [ ok ]" and nothing happens.